# Pip install - Python 2.7 - Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I download the get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ . Then i changed path in: system-variable environment into :  C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages
after that i tried to run in from the cmd and this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**For New versions**

Older versions of python may not have pip installed and get-pip will throw errors. Please update your python (2.7.15 as of Aug 12, 2018).

All current versions have an option to install pip and add it to the path.

Steps:

1. Open `Powershell` as admin. (`win+x` then `a`)
2. Type `python -m pip install <package>`.

If python is not in PATH, it'll throw an error saying unrecognized cmd. To fix, simply add it to the path as mentioned below[1].

**[OLD Answer]**

Python 2.7 must be having pip pre-installed.

Try installing your package by:

1. Open cmd as admin. (`win+x` then `a`)
2. Go to scripts folder: `C:\Python27\Scripts`
3. Type `pip install "package name"` .

Note: Else reinstall python: https://www.python.org/downloads/

[1] Also note: You must be in `C:\Python27\Scripts` in order to use pip command, Else add it to your path by typing:
`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","$env:Path;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User")`

Comment: I think Python 2.7.1 does not come with pip. No such file/dir in the `Scripts` subfolder.

Comment: my Python 2.7.8 does not have pip by default.

Answer (score 8):

Download pip script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then run using python as:-

```
python get-pip.py
```

or you can use python to install modules directly

```
python -m pip install <module>
```

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that in python 2.7 pip is installed by default. if it is not then you can execute

`python -m ensurepip --default-pip`

This worked for me.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/installing/

Comment: "ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python" :/

Comment: doesnt work: `:\Python27\python.exe: No module named ensurepip`

Answer (score 4):

This is one way of installing pip on a Windows system.

1. Download the "get-pip" python script from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. Save the file as `getpip.py`
3. Run it from cmd: `python getpip.py install`

Comment: still i get the same result :-( what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this issue before with 2.7.14. Fixed it by :

1. Re-install python 2.7.14
2. During the installation, select default path and put a check mark in the installation options to add python to windows path i.e. environmental variables.
3. After installation is complete, go to System from the Control Panel, select Advanced system settings, and clicking Environment Variables.
4. Verify that the system variable "path" has "C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts;" added to the list.
5. In cmd, run "where python" and then "where pip". Which will show for example:

   ```
   λ where python
   C:\Python\python.exe

   λ where pip
   C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe
   ```
6. Run pip, then it should show different pip run command options.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to you environment variable `PATH`.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

This path will contain the `pip` executable file. Make sure it exist. If it doesn't then you'll need to install it using the [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script.

Additonally, you can read the following [link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

pip is installed by default when we install Python in windows.
After setting up the environment variables path for python executables, we can run python interpreter from the command line on windows `CMD`
After that, we can directly use the python command with pip option to install further packages as following:-

```
C:\ python -m pip install python_module_name
```

This will install the module using pip.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first download the [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and then run the command :

python get-pip.py