# can't install pip anymore with python 2.7?

Tags: python, pip, eol

I wanted to use a python script compatible with python 2.7 (but not 3.8)

I need pip to make the script work but looks like I can't install pip anymore ? I tried with get-pip.py , but it's not working :

```
user@DESKTOP-J9T7UBF
$ get-pip.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp2kztqk\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:387: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

Comment: Python 2.x closed and have no longer support and continuetion from January 1, 2021

Comment: yeah I know , but there is no way to keep using scripts compatible only with 2.7?

Comment: Is that really _all_ the output? The last line is a warning, not an error.

Comment: you can downgrade your pip and install the packages in that manner

Comment: It's better to switch to Python 3. Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html to convert.

Comment: You should download a pip version compatible with python2.7:

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Answer (score 16):

```
pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: why should it be accepted?  If you don't already have pip installed, you cannot possibly ask pip to upgrade itself

Answer (score 8):

The latest pip has [dropped support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id1) for Python 2
And you cannot install the latest pip via [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) using Python 2.7.

Update: Found an answer here with the script for Python 2.7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866547/429476.

---

You should upgrade to Python 3.
You can use your Linux package manager if you using a Linux distro which have only Python2.7. Note - it installs an older version of Pip that that comes from above script.

> If you installed Python from a package manager on Linux, you should always install pip for that Python installation using the same source.
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ --> https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/

```
# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1883k  100 1883k    0     0  6584k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 6584k

# python get-pip.py --user

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpyG_UJ3/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
# sudo apt-get install python-pip
# python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah pip has dropped it's support to python 2.7. If you still want to use it for python 2.7, downgrading the pip will help you:

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```

Answer (score 3):

### A working solution:

1. Have an installed python2
2. Have an installed python3 (yes 3)
3. Install a legacy pip to python3 (eg 9):
   `python3 -m pip install --upgrade "pip==9"`
4. Find where it has been installed to: `python3 -m pip show pip`
5. Copy to python2's PATH:

   `sudo cp -r /home/usr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-9.0.0.dist-info/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

   `sudo cp -r /home/raczb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
6. Check: `python2.7 -m pip --version`
7. Re-upgrade python3's pip.

Answer (score 3):

An other working solution based on `get-pip.py` that doesn't downgrade python3 pip version:

```
curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/get-pip/20.3.4/get-pip.py' -o get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
```

Explanation: pip 21.0 has dropped support for Python 2.7 in January 2021

Answer (score 3):

PIP can install in python2.7 using this below command

```
python2.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that no specific version of `pip` was specified, and therefore, the script is trying to install the latest version (21 or later). Try specifying an older version, e.g.

```sh
python get-pip.py 'pip==20.3.1'
```

Documented: https://github.com/pypa/get-pip

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I tried to specify an older version but I got "ERROR: Invalid requirement: "'pip==20.3.1'" (I tried differents versions)

Comment: Try specifying a specific python to run with, e.g. `python2.7 get-pip.py`

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this script **only** compatible with Python 2.7? Try to update the script to a non-deprecated version, then run it.
2. Open the Python 2.7 installer, go to Advanced options and look for an 'Install `pip`' checkmark, since in the later releases of Python did come with an 'Install `pip`' checkmark, in Advanced options.
3. Try attaining the module by manual methods i.e Look on the website of the desired module and install to `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

If none of the above solutions are of assistance, I suggest you consult [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700063/pip-install-python-2-7-windows-7). I will inform you that Python 2.7 was considered as deprecated as of January 1st, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can no longer install or downgrade pip from the installer itself.
Solution:

**Step 1**: If you have a working older version of python make a list of all modules that you have or need (this will come in handy in future projects if you move to another computer).

**Step 2**: Download and unzip *setuptools-44.1.1* (because pip needs it) and install it using *Powershell* with admin privileges going to the location of the *setup.py* file. Use the following command:

> py -2.7 setup.py install

**Step 3**: Download and unzip *pip-20.3.4*; and repeat *Powershell* procedure from step 2.

Now you have installed the most recent older version of pip for python 2.7.

I think now I will have to manually download all modules from python 2.7 that I have and need so that I can reliably install them again or in another computer because those versions are no longer supported.
Many people recommend to upgrade to newer versions, but what they don't seem to understand is that many other software APIs require older versions. Many of us don't have the money to upgrade the software as well.