# pip install failing on python2

Tags: python, pip, linux-mint

Following the instructions on this page to install pip on python2 https://linuxhint.com/installing_pip_linux_mint/

It's failing at the last step,
`$ sudo python2 get-pip.py`

with this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmp2aZyDl/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried to look everywhere for a solution, but can't find one. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `f"some string {some_variable}"` is Python 3.6+ syntax, are you sure you're using the right `get-pip.py` for Python 2?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using the right ```get-pip.py```.  According to the instructions on the webpage, I added the universe repository, ran apt update, installed python2, which I already had, and ran this command ```$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py```, followed by ```$ sudo python2 get-pip.py```. Maybe the get-pip has been overwritten by the file required for Python3?

Comment: They really need to update the instructions. The right file for python2 has been moved over to here,
```https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pip broken wiith sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896334/python-pip-broken-wiith-sys-stderr-writeferror-exc)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The correct `get-pip.py` file for python2 has been moved to `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py`

Comment: is there a way to update this to install python via `pyenv install py2.7.1.1`

Comment: The new downloading location is correct but it gives the following error during the installation

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1863k  100 1863k    0     0  2637k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2635k
root@c0010-10213595-1:~# python get-pip.py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0

Answer (score 17):

PIP has dropped support for Python 2.7 in the result you are facing the above  issue, so the only thing is to downgrade the version of pip.

only the following command worked for me...

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```

Comment: This is the only  solution that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. After 30 mins of searching

Answer (score 10):

**This is what you need to do**

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py is the right URL

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error with pip. This command worked for me `sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4`

Answer (score 3):

Try installing previous version of get-pip

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.5/get-pip.py

python get-pip.py

Comment: Can Confirm this works in 2021 on Kali Linux 20.04 :)