# How to install python3 components on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install software that has a [component](https://github.com/project-generator/project_generator) that claims it can be installed using the latest `python3-pip`. I tried `apt-get remove python3-pip` followed by `apt-get install python3-pip` and it reported success, but didn't actually work:

```
% pip2 --version
ppip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
% pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 12
    f"pip{sys.version_info.major}",
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the simplest way to install python3 components in Ubuntu 16?

(For what it's worth, I noticed some people have had [somewhat similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896334/upgrading-pip-fails-with-syntax-error-caused-by-sys-stderr-writeferror-exc) with pip2, maybe because they accidently "upgraded" pip3 to an unstable version. It's possible that this could have happened on my system, but I'm not sure why `apt-get` wouldn't fix it).

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is out of standard support, so you should [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/301745), unless you're on a legacy system with ESM.

Comment: You somehow have a `pip` version installed that requires a newer Python version than you have - the f-string feature that's generating the syntax error was added in Python 3.6, I think.

Comment: @jasonharper I have both Python 3.5.2 and Python 3.6.13 installed. Why is `pip3` using the wrong one? Actually pip3 starts with `#!/usr/bin/python3` so then what is it doing using Python3.6 syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 --version` is the wrong syntax.

`python3.6 -m pip --version` is the [right syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)