# python 2.7 dateutil install in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil, ubuntu-21.04

My Ubuntu 21.04 came with preinstalled with python 3.

I installed python 2.7 in parallel since all my programs are in python 2.7.

In my modules, `import dateutil` is used.

Since the system default is python 3, how do I install python-dateutil in python 2.7?

Thanks.

Comment: @aaossa I tried it. Result is --- vin@vinLap:~$ python2.7 -m pip install dateutil
/usr/bin/python2.7: No module named pip

Comment: @aaossa ---   :~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip it results in error --   Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate

Comment: Looks like pip has dropped support for python 2.7

Comment: for pip, solution of @betontalpfa worked     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558034/cant-install-pip-anymore-with-python-2-7

Comment: @aaossa $ python2.7 -m pip install dateutil
Collecting dateutil
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: )                                                            
No matching distribution found for dateutil
You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: @aaossa yes I tried it. But it is not there. ```>>> import dateutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

Comment: @aaossa ```$ python2.7
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  9 2021, 11:09:26) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210306] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dateutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil```

Comment: Try `python2.7 -m pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: @aaossa exception encountered ... ```You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.                                                                     ```

Comment: That's a waning, not an error. Did it show any additional output?

Comment: @aaossa ```sudo``` was missing. Now it is installed. Thank you very much. You may add it as an answer. I will tag it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTR, these steps were necessary:

1. Install `pip` in Python 2.7. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620660/3281097) in another SO question worked for OP.
2. Install `dateutil` using the corresponding `pip` version:

   ```
   sudo python2.7 -m pip install python-dateutil
   ```